# Changing / coercing multiple colums of a tibble while avoiding a loop

Tags: r, tibble

I have a tibble with several columns in which numbers are stored as text:

```
my_tbl <- tibble(names = letters[1:5],
                 value1 = as.character(runif(5)), 
                 value2 = as.character(runif(5)))
```

Now, I'd like to change the type of these columns ("value1" and "value2") from character to numeric. Only option I've found is using a for-loop:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(my_tbl)) {
  my_tbl[[i]] <- as.numeric(my_tbl[[i]])
}
```

Is there a possibility to do this without a loop?

Comment: You can try `my_tbl[seq(2, ncol(df))] <- lapply(my_tbl[seq(2, ncol(df))], as.numeric)`. You can not avoid iterating though

Comment: True - many thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you could do something like `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(my_tbl[,c("value1","value2")])),nrow = nrow(my_tbl))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mutate_if` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

my_tbl %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)


my_tbl 
## A tibble: 5 x 3
## Groups:   names [5]
#  names value1 value2
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a      0.427 0.0191
#2 b      0.817 0.300 
#3 c      0.108 0.158 
#4 d      0.394 0.643 
#5 e      0.775 0.311
```

Comment: Many thanks - I had searched dplyr for a suitable function, but obviously missed the "mutate_if".

Comment: Glad that this helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

With `purrr` you could do this:

If you already know your target columns :

```
library(purrr)
modify_at(my_tbl,-1,as.numeric)
```

If you need to detect them:

```
modify_if(my_tbl,~is.character(.) && !any(grepl("[:alpha:]",.)),as.numeric)

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   names value1 value2
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a      0.715 0.943 
# 2 b      0.639 0.128 
# 3 c      0.471 0.0395
# 4 d      0.374 0.374 
# 5 e      0.500 0.800
```

using `dplyr` instead of `purrr`, these will yield the same results:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_at(my_tbl,-1,as.numeric)
mutate_if(my_tbl,~is.character(.) && !any(grepl("[:alpha:]",.)),as.numeric)
```

The base `R` translations:

```
my_tbl[-1] <- lapply(my_tbl[-1],as.numeric)
my_tbl[] <- lapply(my_tbl,function(x)
  if (is.character(x) && !any(grepl("[:alpha:]",x))) as.numeric(x)
  else x)
```

Comment: Many thanks - in this case I know the target columns - so, the "modify_at" really is an elegant solution.

Comment: I modified my answer a bit, putting `-1` instead of  `2:ncol(my_tbl)`, and I added the `dplyr` equivalent.